# Implementation of the Polynomial Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: polynomials, number-theory

I would like an implementation of the Chinese Remainder Theorem for polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, that is, a function

```
PolynomialCRT[{f_1,...,f_n},{m_1,...,m_n},x]
```

thet returns the polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of smallest degree such that
$$
f(x)\equiv f_i(x)\mod m_i(x),
$$
where $f_i,m_i\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and the $m_i$ are pairwise coprime.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be straightforward to do this two at a time, using PolynomialExtendedGCD as the primary tool.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for your hint. Following it I succeeded in defining the function PolynomialCRT.

Comment: You can post it here as a separate response. That way the Q has an A, and it is available should others in future make similar queries. That is to say, in a circumstance like this, it is not frowned upon if one answers one's own question.

Answer (score 11):

Following Daniel's comment, I post my solution:

```
PolynomialCRT[pol_List, mod_List, x_] := Module[{m, q, l},
  l = Length[pol];
  m = Table[Times @@ Drop[mod, {i}], {i, l}];
  q = Table[PolynomialExtendedGCD[m[[i]], mod[[i]], x][[2, 1]], {i, l}];
  Simplify[(q pol).m]
  ]
```

There is no error checking code (for instance, `pol` and `mod` have the same length).

Comment: Nice and short (and an upvote of course). One comment: if total degree is high, it could be faster to do it in pairs, then combining paired results in pairs, etc. That would tend to keep the degrees of the two moduli products balanced. We did this once upon a time in integer CRA code and it made a notable difference in terms of speed.

Comment: +1. Sometimes the resulting polynomial is of degree more than necessary, so the last line should be changed to `PolynomialRemainder[Simplify[(q pol).m], PolynomialLCM @@ mod, x]`. Will `Table[Times@@...` line slower than procedural approach?